# "Category" not defined keyword in Python Django

Tags: django

So I am following Jacob Kaplan-Moss' beginning Django tutorial and he asks to implement the following in `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Package(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    version     = models.CharField(max_length=300,
                               blank=True)
    home_page   = models.URLField(blank=True)
    summary     = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    keyboards   = models.TextField(blank=True)
    categories  = models.ManyToManyField(Category,
                             related_name="packages")
```

However when I run `manage.py validate`, it points out that "Category" is not recognized. I just don't know what does he intend it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Category should be another class. For example

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Comment: maybe Category is defined later in your source code: If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself: `categories  = models.ManyToManyField("Category", related_name="packages")` see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey